# How do I get my constructor and functions to work so my main() is able to display both the string and int data?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am learning about functions and classes, and wrote my own code.  I used the constructor to just initialize the variables. I have a function that is supposed to get the info I initialized with the constructor and allow me to display it.  However, it doesn't want to work. I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. My error code says that I have unresolved externals because of my "void" function. I thought my function was not returning anything but rather just displaying the input it got from the initialization of the constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Berries {

    string Nameofberries;
    int Price;

public:

    Berries (string N,int B)
    {
        Nameofberries = N;
        Price = B;
    }

    void GetBerryInfo(const Berries& B)
    {
        cout << B.Nameofberries << endl;
        cout <<  B.Price << endl;
    }
};

void GetBerryInfo (const Berries& B);

int main () 
{
    Berries Berryinfo1( "Raspberries", 7);
    cout << GetBerryInfo;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << Berryinfo1.GetBerryInfo();` instead.

Comment: You should re-read the part about objects in a good C++ book before contuining.

Comment: Get rid of the line `void GetBerryInfo (const Berries& B);`.  It isn't doing anything besides hiding the real issue, causing errors at link time instead of compile time.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense for `GetBerryInfo` to be both a member function and take a `Berries` as a parameter.  It seems like it should be printing the name and price of the *current* `Berries`, not some other `Berries`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several mistakes.

```
void GetBerryInfo(const Berries& B)
{
    cout <<  B.Nameofberries << endl;
    cout <<  B.Price << endl;
}
```

should be

```
void GetBerryInfo()
{
    cout <<  Nameofberries << endl;
    cout <<  Price << endl;
}
```

==================================================================

```
void GetBerryInfo (const Berries& B);
```

should be removed.

==================================================================

```
 cout << GetBerryInfo;
```

should be

```
 Berryinfo1.GetBerryInfo();
```

==================================================================

All computer langauges are fussy, you have to get the details right, as well as understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you wanted:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>
# include <string>
using namespace std;

class Berries {

string Nameofberries;
int Price;

public:

Berries (string N,int B)
{
Nameofberries = N;
Price = B;
}
void GetBerryInfo()
{
    cout <<  Nameofberries << endl;
    cout <<  Price << endl;
}
};

int main () 
{
Berries Berryinfo1( "Raspberries", 7);
Berryinfo1.GetBerryInfo();

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

A couple of points on your mistakes:

- `GetBerryInfo()` was declared inside the class. You don't need to re-declare it in the global scope. That 2nd declaration should be removed.
- To be invoked, functions (like `GetBerryInfo`) must have `()` at the end of them like so: `GetBerryInfo()`.
- There is no point for `GetBerryInfo()` to take `Berries` as a paremeter. It is a member function that is part of the class `Berries`. It has access to all data members of a `Berries` instance already.
- You don't need to use `cout` here: `cout << GetBerryInfo;` because the function body already sends the data members to `cout`. This function returns `void` so it doesn't make sense to send this to `cout` anyway.